# React native with expo: ‘react-navigation does not exist in the haste module map’

Tags: javascript, react-native

I’m a beginner working on my first app with react native and expo. I’m having trouble getting the navigation to work. When I run the app, I get the error ‘react-navigation does not exist in the haste module map’. I’ve installed react navigation through the command line and ran install npm to install dependancies.

Comment: Please show the code or share a expo snack.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problems few weeks back , please follow the steps below :

1. Open terminal and navigate to project root directory.
2. write 'rm -rf node_modules' in the terminal to remove the node modules.
3. write 'npm install' in order to install the node modules again
4. write 'cd ios'.
5. write 'rm -r build' to clear the old build.
6. come back to the root folder of project again and run the project.

Your code will run smoothly.